# Prebid.js individual sizes sent only to a specific bidder

Tags: prebid.js, prebid

I would like to set individual sizes in Prebid.js sent only to a specific bidder. I checked and the configuration below is incorrect

```
   "Adunit_mobile1": {
      "google": {
        "slot": "/GAM_network_ID/GAM_path/GAM_Adunit_name",
        "lazyLoad": true,
        "hb": true,
         "sizes": [[300, 600], [320, 50], [300, 250], [320, 100]],
        "sizeMappings": [],
        "mediaTypes": {
          "banner": {
            "sizes": [[300, 250], [300, 600], [320, 100], [320, 50]]
          }
        },
        "bids": [
{
            "bidder": "bidder_1",
            "params": {
              "siteId": "XYZ"
            }
          },
{
            "bidder": "bidder_2",
            "sizes": [1, 1],
            "params": {
              "uid": "XYZ"
            }
          },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for your bidder params [here](https://docs.prebid.org/dev-docs/bidders.html) and see if a size entry is allowed. Different possibilities :

- no size param available => look for the dedicated documentation
- size param available => specific size ID from your bidder's API or array of sizes

Please also note : if your bidder allows you to define sizes, it would, most of the time, be declared within its "params" :

```
"bidder": "bidder",
"params": {
   "param": "value",
   "sizes" : [1,1]
 }
```

Conclusion : it depends on your bidder's capabilities.